# Destination folder not properly set

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code that reads an emails' category/email address/subject/sender name. It then searches for this info in different Excel tables. If found it locates the destination folder to move read emails.

Here's where the problem starts.
On the first cycle it IDs the destination folder and moves the email. On the next eligible email, when it tries to assign the identified folder name it either keeps the previous destination folder or it is set to nothing.

```vb
Sub MoveEmail()
Public objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object
Public olApp As Outlook.Application
Public olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Public SrcFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Public DestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Public colStores As Stores
Public oStore As Store
Public objCategories As Categories
Public objCategory As Category

Public objVariant As Variant
Public FolderType As Variant
Public FolderName As String

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Sets the Mailname equals to what is selected from the dropdown list
MailName = ShMain.cboMailbox.Value -- Get the name of the shared mailbox from a dropdown menu

'Finds mailbox real name
' The name on the ShMain.cboMailbox.Value dropdown list is just a 'friendly' name so the shared mailbox real name is found on the table below using Vlookup
MailRealName = Application.VLookup(MailName, ShRef.Range(RangeTemp), 2, False)
Set SrcFolder = olNS.Folders(MailRealName).Folders("Inbox")

EmailCount = SrcFolder.Items.Count

For EmailCount = SrcFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set objVariant = SrcFolder.Items.Item(EmailCount)
    DoEvents

    If objVariant.UnRead = False Then
        
        On Error Resume Next
        TempEmailAddress1 = objVariant.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
        TempEmailAddress2 = objVariant.SenderEmailAddress
        
        If InStr(TempEmailAddress2, "/") <> 0 Then
            TempEmailAddress = TempEmailAddress1
        ElseIf TempEmailAddress1 = "" And TempEmailAddress2 <> "" Then
            TempEmailAddress = TempEmailAddress2
        Else
            TempEmailAddress = TempEmailAddress1
        End If

'this code just makes sure the variable has a valid email since the email couldve been sent within or outside the company
        
        DomainName = Split(TempEmailAddress, "@")
        DomainName = DomainName(UBound(DomainName))
        SenderName = objVariant.SenderName
        EmailSubject = objVariant.Subject
        EmailCategory = objVariant.Categories
        
        'Changes all variables to lower case
        TempEmailAddress = LCase(TempEmailAddress)
        DomainName = LCase(DomainName)
        SenderName = LCase(SenderName)
        EmailSubject = LCase(EmailSubject)
        EmailCategory = LCase(EmailCategory)
        
'Now that we have the basic information, we use them to search them on the 5 different tables on a diff excel sheet called ShRules:
'Table 1: used to find the email's set category and get the subfolder the email needs to be moved to
'Table 2: used to find the email's domain and get the subfolder the email needs to be moved to
'Table 3: used to find the email address and gets the subfolder the email needs to be moved to
'Table 4: used to find the email subject (key words) and gets the subfolder the email needs to be moved to
'Table 3: used to find the email sender name and gets the subfolder the email needs to be moved to

        '*******************************
        'Moves email based on Category
        '*******************************
LastRow = ShRules.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
        'On Error Resume Next
        x = 3
        Do While x <= LastRow
            If ShRules.Cells(x, 1).Value = ShMain.cboMailbox.Value And EmailCategory = ShRules.Cells(x, 2).Value Then
                FolderType = ShRules.Cells(x, 3).Value
                FolderName = ShRules.Cells(x, 4).Value
'**********
'This is where the Set DestFolder code does not work after the loop does the first cycle
'**********
                Set DestFolder = olNS.Folders(MailRealName).Folders("Inbox").Folders(FolderType).Folders(FolderName)
                Call MoveToFolder
                GoTo LetsContinue
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop

        '*****************************************************************
        'Checks to see if it appears on the table for Email's domain name
        '*****************************************************************
        LastRow = ShRules.Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Row
        'On Error Resume Next
        x = 3
        Do While x <= LastRow
            If ShRules.Cells(x, 6).Value = ShMain.cboMailbox.Value And DomainName = ShRules.Cells(x, 7).Value Then
                FolderType = ShRules.Cells(x, 8).Value
                FolderName = ShRules.Cells(x, 9).Value
'**********
'if it falls under this section - This is where the Set DestFolder code does not work after the loop does the first cycle
'**********
                Set DestFolder = olNS.Folders(MailRealName).Folders("Inbox").Folders(FolderType).Folders(FolderName)
                Call MoveToFolder
                GoTo LetsContinue
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop

        '********************************************************************
         'Checks to see if it appears on the table for Email's email address
        '********************************************************************
        LastRow = ShRules.Range("K1048576").End(xlUp).Row
        'On Error Resume Next
        x = 3
        Do While x <= LastRow
            If ShRules.Cells(x, 11).Value = ShMain.cboMailbox.Value And TempEmailAddress = ShRules.Cells(x, 12).Value Then
                FolderType = ShRules.Cells(x, 13).Value
                FolderName = ShRules.Cells(x, 14).Value
'**********
'if it falls under this section - This is where the Set DestFolder code does not work after the loop does the first cycle                
'**********
                Set DestFolder = olNS.Folders(MailRealName).Folders("Inbox").Folders(FolderType).Folders(FolderName)
                Call MoveToFolder
                GoTo LetsContinue
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop

        '************************************************************
        'Checks to see if it appears on the table for Email Subjects
        '************************************************************
        LastRow = ShRules.Range("P1048576").End(xlUp).Row
        'On Error Resume Next
        x = 3
        Do While x <= LastRow
            If ShRules.Cells(x, 16).Value = ShMain.cboMailbox.Value And InStr(EmailSubject, ShRules.Cells(x, 17).Value) <> 0 Then
                FolderType = ShRules.Cells(x, 18).Value
                FolderName = ShRules.Cells(x, 19).Value
'**********
'if it falls under this section - This is where the Set DestFolder code does not work after the loop does the first cycle
'********** 
                Set DestFolder = olNS.Folders(MailRealName).Folders("Inbox").Folders(FolderType).Folders(FolderName)
                Call MoveToFolder
                GoTo LetsContinue
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop
        
        '***************************************************************
        'Checks to see if it appears on the table for Email sender name
        '***************************************************************
        LastRow = ShRules.Range("U1048576").End(xlUp).Row
        'On Error Resume Next
        x = 3
        Do While x <= LastRow
            If ShRules.Cells(x, 21).Value = ShMain.cboMailbox.Value And ShRules.Cells(x, 22).Value = SenderName Then
                FolderType = ShRules.Cells(x, 23).Value
                FolderName = ShRules.Cells(x, 24).Value
'**********
'if it falls under this section - This is where the Set DestFolder code does not work after the loop does the first cycle
'**********
                Set DestFolder = olNS.Folders(MailRealName).Folders("Inbox").Folders(FolderType).Folders(FolderName)
                Call MoveToFolder
                GoTo LetsContinue
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop
    End If

'    Call ResetVals
LetsContinue:
    'x = x + 1
    Call ResetVals
Next
```

I tried to add `Set DestFolder = Nothing` but it doesn't help.

I noticed that after I get this error, if I run the code again even the first cycle will not assign the DestFolder. It only works again if I close Outlook.

Comment: A side note, but you are mixing early- and late-binding, plus you have two Outlook instances (`Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`) and (`Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`). It would be best to be consistent.

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and see if you get an error, or at least restrict its scope to the *bare minimum* by resetting with `On Error Goto 0`.  Also you're doing too much in one procedure - try breaking out parts of the code into separate subs/functions so it's easier to follow.

Comment: Adding `Set Destfolder = Nothing` before trying to find a destination should help, otherwise if there's no suitable match you still have the previous folder.  Unless you're doing that in ResetVals (are you using a bunch of Globals?)

Comment: @BigBen , , thanks one of them was a comment, I just deleted it

Comment: @Tim Williams. I added the "Set DestFolder = Nothing" before, like you suggested and I keep having the same issue: The variables are successfully found on this line of code ` Set DestFolder = olNS.Folders(MailRealName).Folders("Inbox").Folders(FolderType).Folders(FolderName)`  the "FolderName" variable is found and loaded into the variable but when the next time line comes to Set the DestFolder it returns empty instead of Set DestFolder = "Whatever outlook subfolder name"  The subfolder path is correct as well

Comment: Just noticed you have a bunch of "Public" declarations at the top of your Sub - FYI these will not be accessible to (eg) `MoveToFolder` if that's the intent.  In fact that code will not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to create two instances of the Outlook Application class in the code:

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

So, just remove extra lines of code:

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

Then I'd recommend running the code under the debugger to find the line where it fails. See [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) for more information.

```
Set DestFolder = olNS.Folders(MailRealName).Folders("Inbox").Folders(FolderType).Folders(FolderName)
```

A single line of code contains a lot of property and methods call. It is not clear exactly which call exactly fails. So, I'd recommend breaking the chain of property and method calls and declaring them on separate lines.

Comment: Hi @EugeneAstafiev thanks for the feedback. I removed the extra lines of code. I ran the debuger but i still get the same issue. After the first loop and successfully moving the first email;  When the 2nd loop identifies the new email to move (into a different folder) it does not assign the proper folder name into the DestFolder variable (on that 2nd time the loop runs), it keeps it empty. Im not certain where exactly is the bug

Comment: > Set DestFolder = olNS.Folders(MailRealName).Folders("Inbox").Folders(FolderType).Folders(FolderName)

Comment: Declare each property or method call on a separate line, so you will be able to find which method exactly fails.

Comment: Hi @EugeneAstafiev I followed your suggestion and this is what i found. `Set DestFolder = olNS.Folders(MailRealName).Folders("Inbox").Folders(FolderType).Folders(FolderName)` I Created 3 new variables `Set DestFolder1 = olNS.Folders(MailRealName) then Set DestFolder2 = olNS.Folders(MailRealName).Folders("Inbox").Folders(FolderType) and Set DestFolder3 = olNS.Folders(MailRealName).Folders("Inbox").Folders(FolderType).Folders(FolderName) ` The first 2 variables worked great they updated accordingly. The last one did not work, its what sets the variable to "Nothing" All var types are correct.

Comment: I do want to point out something interesting. If I run the macro, for the first time... as mentioned before the first loop works and moves the email to the correct email but... if i stop the macro on the spot..... then try to run it again the DestFolder2 and DestFolder3 variables now are kept empty.  I need to close outlook entirely, reopen it again... run the macro for it to work again... which is very strange, I don't understand why I have the need to close the outlook app and reopen it in order for the variables to be captured properly on the macro that is on an excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

So after much troubleshooting I found out what the issue was. It seems there's a limitation of how many levels of subfolders you can go down to. My levels were "Mailbox Name" --> Inbox --> Folder Name ---> "Desired subfolder". There are 4 levels, when i removed a single level it worked: "Mailbox Name" --> Folder Name ---> "Desired subfolder"